# not visible trash icon in vue js and Laravel project

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js

working with Vue js and Laravel back end project. using iviewui component as front end library. but following code segment available for the displaying trash icon of the uploaded file.

```
<div class="image_thumb" v-if="data.iconImage">
                <img :src="`/uploads/${data.iconImage}`" />
                <div class="demo-upload-list-cover">
                <Icon type="ios-trash-outline" @click="deleteImage"></Icon> // this is line
                </div>

</div>
```

but when displaying image here not available trash icon for delete the image as well.

console displaying following error message here
`Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: http://localhost:8000/css/all.css Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map`

how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: The source map problem is because you are wrongly referencing your css file, check the name if the file first.

Comment: did you mean my file name should be `bootstrap.min.css.map`